# Label not refreshing

Tags: c#, forms, label

I made a simple program in c# containing 2 forms and an additional class.
I want to update a label showing game year in Form 2 when Enter is pressed in Form 1. The following program works fine and when I press Enter in Form 1, the game year is increased by 1 and accordingly updated on label in Form 2:

FORM 1:

        `private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                Form2 form2 = (Form2)this.MdiParent.MdiChildren[2];
                form2.updateLabelValue();
            }
        }`

FORM 2:

```
//Update value in form
    public void updateLabelValue()
    {
        game.increaseYear();

        gameYearLabel.Text = Math.Abs(Game.gameYear).ToString();
    }
```

GAME CLASS:

```
public class Game
{
    public static int gameYear = -4000;

    public void increaseYear()
    {
        gameYear += 1;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to make the Form 1 (when Enter is pressed) first call GAME class and from there update the value in Form 2 (so that both forms do not communicate directly but rather through the GAME class):

FORM 1:

        `private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                game.increaseYear();
            }
        }`

FORM 2:

```
//Update value in form
    public void updateLabelValue()
    {
        gameYearLabel.Text = Math.Abs(Game.gameYear).ToString();
    }
```

GAME CLASS:

```
public class Game
{
    public static int gameYear = -4000;

    public void increaseYear()
    {
        gameYear += 1;

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.updateLabelValue();
    }
```

But in this case when I press Enter the label in Form 2 is not updated, even though through debugging I can see that the value has indeed changed, but it won't update on the label itself. I've also tried calling Refresh() but it doesn't help.

Comment: You are creating a new form, updating **the new form's label** and then never showing it.

Comment: `Form2 form2 = (Form2)this.MdiParent.MdiChildren[2];`  Seems risky to think that the form you want to work with is *always* going to be at index 2.

Comment: Form2 is an MDI child form that I show along with 2 other forms side by side (I omitted that part of the code). Simply calling form2.Show() after form2.updateLabelValue() does indeed pop out another instance of the same form with the updated label. However form2.Update() does not seem to update label. How come the first program shown above works but the other doesn't?